# Json Array giving Exception

Tags: android, arrays, json, soap

Below is my Json response -

```
CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response{CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result=[{"ROLE_NAME":"","USER_MOBILE":"","IMEI_NUMBER1":,"USER_ID":30,"ROLE_ID":4,"USER_NAME":""}]; }
```

Below is my code -

```
if (resultlog!= null) {

  try {
    JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray(resultlog);
    for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = resultarray.getJSONObject(i);
      roleName = c.getString("ROLE_NAME");
      userMobile = c.getString("USER_MOBILE");
      imeiNumber = c.getString("IMEI_NUMBER1");
      userId = c.getString("USER_ID");
      roleid = c.getString("ROLE_ID");
      userNmae = c.getString("USER_NAME");
    }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Below is my error

> org.json.JSONException: Value CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response of type
>   java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: First check your json formate

Comment: "IMEI_NUMBER1": value missing

Comment: Can you please log `resultlog` just before you call the `new JSONArray(...)` - it also seems you did not specify value for the property `IMEI_NUMBER1`.

Comment: All key and value both coming properly. I have hide emei no in my ques. Otherwise all value coming...

Comment: Are you getting error on this line     "JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray(resultlog);" I dont think you need JSONArray  here, it should be  "JSONObject" like this JSONObject result = new JSONObject(resultlog);

Answer (score 0):

Below resultLog is your actual json result.

```
    String roleName = "", userMobile = "", imeiNumber = "", userNmae = "";
    int userId = 0, roleid = 0;
```

(or)

If your flow starts with CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response as a jsonObject then you should add below lines of code inside try block.

```
    String resultlog= "{CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response:{CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result:{"ROLE_NAME":"","USER_MOBILE":"","IMEI_NUMBER1":"","USER_ID":30,"ROLE_ID":4,"USER_NAME":""}}}
    JSONObject resultJsonObject = null;
    try {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject(resultlog);
        JSONObject obj2 = obj1.has("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response") ? obj1.getJSONObject("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response") : null;
        resultJsonObject = obj2.has("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result") ? obj2.getJSONObject("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result") : null;
        roleName = resultJsonObject.has("ROLE_NAME") ? resultJsonObject.getString("ROLE_NAME") : "";           
        userMobile = resultJsonObject.has("USER_MOBILE") ? resultJsonObject.getString("USER_MOBILE") : "";
        imeiNumber = resultJsonObject.has("IMEI_NUMBER1") ? resultJsonObject.getString("IMEI_NUMBER1") : "";
        userId = resultJsonObject.has("USER_ID") ? resultJsonObject.getInt("USER_ID") : "";            
        roleid = resultJsonObject.has("ROLE_ID") ? resultJsonObject.getInt("ROLE_ID") : "";            
        userNmae = resultJsonObject.has("USER_NAME") ? resultJsonObject.getString("USER_NAME") : "";           

   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Otherwise use below:

```
     String resultlog = "{\"ROLE_NAME\":\"\",\"USER_MOBILE\":\"\",\"IMEI_NUMBER1\":\"\",\"USER_ID\":30,\"ROLE_ID\":4,\"USER_NAME\":\"\"}";
    try {
        JSONObject resultJsonObject = new JSONObject(resultlog);          
            roleName = resultJsonObject.has("ROLE_NAME") ? resultJsonObject.getString("ROLE_NAME") : "";           
            userMobile = resultJsonObject.has("USER_MOBILE") ? resultJsonObject.getString("USER_MOBILE") : "";
            imeiNumber = resultJsonObject.has("IMEI_NUMBER1") ? resultJsonObject.getString("IMEI_NUMBER1") : "";
            userId = resultJsonObject.has("USER_ID") ? resultJsonObject.getInt("USER_ID") : "";            
            roleid = resultJsonObject.has("ROLE_ID") ? resultJsonObject.getInt("ROLE_ID") : "";            
            userNmae = resultJsonObject.has("USER_NAME") ? resultJsonObject.getString("USER_NAME") : "";           

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is using the entire string as a `JSONArray`.

Remove **`CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response`** from the log. Then create a new `JSONObject` from what remains, and then get `JSONArray`

 **`CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result`** from the object and loop to get the object(s) from the `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code

```
try{
   JSONObject result=resultlog.getJSONObject("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response");
   JSONArray resultarray=result.getJSONArray("CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result");
      for(int i=0;i<resultarray.length();i++){
         JSONObject c=resultarray.getJSONObject(i);
         roleName=c.getString("ROLE_NAME");
         userMobile=c.getString("USER_MOBILE");
         imeiNumber=c.getString("IMEI_NUMBER1");
         userId=c.getString("USER_ID");
         roleid=c.getString("ROLE_ID");
         userNmae=c.getString("USER_NAME");
      }
 } catch(JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resultlog string seems to be

> **CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response**{CallWMDefaultWithRef1Result=[{"ROLE_NAME":"","USER_MOBILE":"","IMEI_NUMBER1":,"USER_ID":30,"ROLE_ID":4,"USER_NAME":""}]; }

It Contains a string(**CallWMDefaultWithRef1Response**) along with JSON content. You should pass only the JSON content to the new JSONArray() constructor.

To extract the JSON Array from the resultlog, try

```
resultlog = resultlog.substring(jsonStr.indexOf("["), jsonStr.lastIndexOf("]")+1);
```

So resultlog will be

> [{"ROLE_NAME":"","USER_MOBILE":"","IMEI_NUMBER1":,"USER_ID":30,"ROLE_ID":4,"USER_NAME":""}]
>
> **NOTE : here a litereal value is missing after "IMEI_NUMBER1"**
>   **which will throw a JSONException. You should correct this in server to**
>   **include an empty string after IMEI_NUMBER1.**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with very easy Step--

```
try {
      JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray(resultlog.getProperty(0));
      for (int i = 0; i < resultarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = resultarray.getJSONObject(i);
                roleName = c.getString("ROLE_NAME");
                userMobile = c.getString("USER_MOBILE");
                imeiNumber = c.getString("IMEI_NUMBER1");
                userId = c.getString("USER_ID");
                roleid = c.getString("ROLE_ID");
                userNmae = c.getString("USER_NAME");
        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Please like my answer for help others.

Happy Coding..